# Typeahead.js transport stop firing after a while

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm using Typeahead.js v0.10.4 with Bloodhound remote option. It works as I expected for a while, but hitting a lot of backspace and typing again just stop all functionality. I made a tiny test for this:

```
var bhOptions = {
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '%QUERY',
        transport: function(url, o, onSuccess, onError) {
            $('#console').prepend(url + "\n");
        }
    }
};

var saSearch = new Bloodhound( bhOptions );
saSearch.initialize();

$('#search').typeahead({}, {
    source: saSearch.ttAdapter()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SubZtep/Lkh68/

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I've tried to play with rate limit but it didn't help.

Just for the record I found a similar issue but it didn't solve my problem:
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/149